# Using Xamarin (Mono C#) and .Net to generate the same key

Tags: c#, .net, hash, mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to get the user to enter a pin and then use a formula to create a time sensitive String. I.E. if you call the function one minute later the string will be completely different. I then take this string run it through the SHA1 algorithm. My problem is that I need the .Net and Mono libraries to produces the same result and they are not. I am using Xmarin studio to deploy the mono library to android. I am using the .Net 3.5 framework to deploy my web service.

I have confirmed that the two strings that are passed as arguments to the sha1 aglorithm are the same on both android and .net.
The problem is that the output of the SHA1 algorithm is different. I believe this is because of how they are implemented in the different libraries. The actual C# code is the same on both devices.

Does anyone know a simple algorithm I could use that would not rely on the libraries? Or even better, suggestions on what I could be doing wrong.

This is the Code for my C# 3.5 webservice

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


namespace rasToken
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,    uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string rasEncrypt(String userid)
    {
        //get pin from data base
        String pin = "1234";
       return generateToken(pin);

    }
    public string generateToken(String pin)
    {
        String debug="";

        int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        debug+="month: "+month;
        int year = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;
        debug+="year: "+year;
        int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
         debug+="hour: "+hour;
         int minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        debug+="minute: "+minute;
        int day = DateTime.Now.Day;
        debug+="day: "+day;
        int concat = month * minute * year * day * hour * 7857564;
        concat=Math.Abs(concat);
        SHA1 sh1 = SHA1.Create();
        String hash = concat + "23117345423219" + pin;
        //MD5 hasher = MD5.Create();
        byte[] result = sh1.ComputeHash(getBytes(hash));


        String final = getString(result);



       return final.Substring(0, 8)+hash;
    }

    private byte[] getBytes(String hash){
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        return encoding.GetBytes(hash);           
    }

    private String getString(byte[] bytes)
    {

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        String clean = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes).Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
        return clean;
        //return encoding.GetString(bytes);
    }

}
}
```

This is my code for the mono android library

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace raskey
{
[Activity (Label = "raskey", MainLauncher = true)]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    //int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);
        EditText input = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.pin);
        //button.Click += delegate {
        //  button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
        //};
        input.KeyPress+=(object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e) => {
            if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter) {
                generateToken(input.Text);
                Toast.MakeText (this, generateToken(input.Text), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        };

    }
    public string generateToken(String pin)
    {
        String debug="";

        int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        debug+="month: "+month;
        int year = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;
        debug+="year: "+year;
        int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        debug+="hour: "+hour;
        int minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        debug+="minute: "+minute;
        int day = DateTime.Now.Day;
        debug+="day: "+day;
        int concat = month * minute * year * day * hour * 7857564;
        concat=Math.Abs(concat);
        SHA1 sh1 = SHA1.Create();
        String hash = concat + "23117345423219" + pin;
        //MD5 hasher = MD5.Create();
        byte[] result = sh1.ComputeHash(getBytes(hash));


        String final = getString(result);



        return final.Substring(0, 8)+" "+hash;
    }

    private byte[] getBytes(String hash){
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding  encoding=new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        return encoding.GetBytes(hash);           
    }

    private String getString(byte[] bytes)
    {

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        String clean = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes).Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
        return clean;
        //return encoding.GetString(bytes);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: SHA1 is a standard algorithm. Every (correct) implementation will produce the same results.  This is a problem in your code, probably about encodings.

Comment: Okay, I'll update with the code for both projects in a second.

Comment: I just updated, and fyi don't mind the 1234 that's hard coded. I always enter 1234 as the pin on the android device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source code looks different for the server and client, e.g.

```
  return final.Substring(0, 8)+hash;
```

and

```
  return final.Substring(0, 8)+" "+hash;
```

and that will return a different hash value.

For debugging you might want to skip the hash part and use the *token* to see if they match (if not you know your issue is not crypto related).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I figured it out and it just turns out that I'm just dumb. I had tried to use android in my layout to force the user to only enter numbers. This resulted in an empty string being passed to the input of the generateToken method on my android device. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your `hash` strings are different. You should log them and make sure they match.